# Thumbnail wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, thumbnails

I need a wordpress plugin to generate thumbnails in my posts. 
I need the same size for all images in the post, for more order and space.

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [nextGenGallery plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/). It not only makes thumbnails with user settings provided, but it is also advanced gallery with many other features like albums, photos in the posts, slideshows etc.

Comment: Find more thumbnail plugins in the WordPress plugins directory here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=thumbnails

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to [THIS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-thumbnail-editor/screenshots/) plugin.

> Fed up with the lack of automated tools to properly crop and scale
>   post thumbnails? Maybe this plugin can help.